# How to search text of a data table in jsf , row by row?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have a search text and I have to search the input text in the same page just like we do search in any web page by ctrl+f it will displays all the occurrences of the input text how to do it in jsf+icefaces. My xhtml is

```
                                    <h:inputText id="searchTextField" size="12" maxlength="10" value="#{editSplitAsgnsBean.searchTextField}">
                                        </h:inputText>

                                        <ice:commandButton styleClass="buttonPurple" value="#{msgs['EditSplitAsgns.Button.searchButton']}" id="searchButton"
                                            actionListener="#{editSplitAsgnsController.searchButton}">

                                            <ace:ajax execute="@this" render="@sortDataTable" />
                                        </ice:commandButton>
```

in my controller I am doing this but getting NullPointerException

```
public void searchButton(ActionEvent e) {
    searchTextField = editSplitAsgnsBean.getSearchTextField();
    if(isNullOrEmpty(searchTextField)) { return; }
    if(!validateInput(searchTextField, true, 10)){
        popupHandler.displayMessage(getMessageString(EDIT_SPLIT_ASSIGNMENT_SEARCHSTRING_VALIDATION_MESSAGE));
        return;
    }
    resetSearchData();
    findMatchedColumn(SEARCH);

}
public void nextButton(ActionEvent e) {
    findMatchedColumn(NEXT);
}
private void findMatchedColumn(String action) {
    EditSplitAsgnsData searchRow = null;

    String search = editSplitAsgnsBean.getSearchTextField();
    if (NEXT.equals(action) && lastFoundIndex != -1) {
        index++;
        if (matchedColumns.size() > index) {
            selectColumn = matchedColumns.get(index);
            selectCell(getTable(), lastFoundIndex, selectColumn);
            return;
        }
    }
    int newFoundIndex = getTable().findRow(search, selectedColumns, lastFoundIndex + 1, DataTable.SearchType.CONTAINS, true);
    matchedColumns.clear();
    index = 0;
    if (SEARCH.equals(action) && newFoundIndex == -1) {
        popupHandler.displayMessage(getMessageString(COMMON_NOSORTSCHEME_DATA_MSG, search));
        return;
    }
    if (NEXT.equals(action) && newFoundIndex == -1) {
        popupHandler.displayMessage(getMessageString(EDIT_SPLIT_ASSIGNMENT_SEARCHSTRING_VALIDATION_MESSAGE, search));
        searchFlag = false;
        selectCell(getTable(), lastFoundIndex, selectColumn);
        return;
    }
    searchFlag = true;
    getTable().navigateToRow(newFoundIndex);
    getTable().setRowIndex(newFoundIndex);
    searchRow = (EditSplitAsgnsData) getTable().getRowData();
    searchMatches(searchRow, search);
    if (!CollectionsUtil.isNullOrEmpty(matchedColumns)) {
        selectColumn = matchedColumns.get(index);
    }
    lastFoundIndex = newFoundIndex;
    selectCell(getTable(), lastFoundIndex, selectColumn);
}

private void resetSearchData() {
    lastFoundIndex = -1;
    selectColumn = -1;
    searchFlag = false;
}
```

Stack Trace

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fedex.emea.gss.controller.EditSplitAsgnsController.findMatchedColumn(EditSplitAsgnsController.java:483)
at com.fedex.emea.gss.controller.EditSplitAsgnsController.searchButton(EditSplitAsgnsController.java:464)
at com.fedex.emea.gss.controller.EditSplitAsgnsController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6f1285ca.invoke(<generated>)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
at com.fedex.emea.gss.controller.EditSplitAsgnsController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$6e6697f4.searchButton(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:148)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:775)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:786)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1251)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
```

I am new to jsf so dont know how to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `execute="@this"`, this means you are only sending the command button in your request but not your Textfield.

In order to fix this, here are possible solutions

1. `execute="@form"` will send all the form attributes in the request
2. `execute="searchTextField"` will send the searchTextFieldId in the request. This is the best solution. Take care of the path of the `"searchFieldId"`. You need to use the full path

As another advice, I usually use the `"listener"` attribute of the `"ajax"` and avoid `"actionListener"`. Theoritically you dont need ajax with commandbutton. commandButton uses already ajax. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Shady for your reply, I will try the solutions provided by you.